# Resolve.Alias in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to reactjs and I already did read [article](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) but I can't figure it how. I'm trying to create an alias when importing. This is working

`import BootstrapCss from '../../../dist/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';`

but doing this is no luck

`import BootstrapCss from 'bootstrap';`

In my `webpack.config.js` I have this

`...
resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', 'css', '.scss', '.eot', '.ttf', '.svg', '.woff'],
      modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'scripts', 'images', 'fonts', 'dist'],
      alias: {
        bootstrap : path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
      }
    }
...`

and I don't know how to change the path of node_modules path I'm getting error at

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bootstrap' in E:\path-to-folder\src\components\home
resolve module bootstrap in E:\path-to-folder\src\components\home
  looking for modules in E:\path-to-folder\node_modules
    E:\path-to-folder\node_modules\bootstrap doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' bootstrap in E:\path-to-folder\node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this Babel plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-webpack-alias
which should allow you to use these aliases in your front-end code. (Provided you have a working Babel configuration)

Other than that, it would seem that adding a `~` before your alias should do the trick. (ref: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/945)